# Is there any indication that someone is cast as Anakin in The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

There is some recycled dialog in the second teaser for *The Force Awakens*, with a voiceover by Luke:

> The force runs strong in my family. My father **has** it…

Assuming that the dialog is from *The Force Awakens* and not just lifted from *Return of the Jedi*, it implies Anakin is still present. He was seen as a force ghost at the end of *Jedi*. So conceivably could still be around.

But someone would need to play him. Have there been any rumors about this?

Comment: Is it definitely Luke speaking and not his presumed son?

Comment: “He was seen as a force ghost at the end of *Jedi*.” THAT’S NOT MY JEDI. “But someone would need to play him.” I dunno, things have changed since *The Phantom Menace*. Movies these days sometimes render entire scenes/characters in CGI.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - he actually was: http://im.ziffdavisinternational.com/ign_es/screenshot/default/screen-shot-2013-12-28-at-222444_qhpu.jpg

Comment: @DarthMelkor: this is very true, sorry, I just associate the name Anakin with all that unpleasantness in the noughties.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - I just pretend it never happened. :)

Comment: @DarthMelkor I'd sort of assumed that Episodes I,II & III were a Sith plan to destroy the will of modern Jedi.

Comment: I feel there is too much speculation abound as we only have rumours to run off of as yet, and things are still rapidly changing. As such I have closed this for the time being.

Comment: I'm specifically asking for evidence.

Comment: On a side note, he says "The Force IS strong in my family..", not "The Force runs strong..."  As to the actual question - Vader/Anakin is now "one with the Force", so he still exists in a way.  In an out-of-universe sense, though, they may have wanted his dialogue to mirror the quote from Return of the Jedi as much as possible.

Comment: @Gaius - It was definitely Luke speaking.  http://www.businessinsider.com/mark-hamill-voice-over-star-wars-teaser-trailer-2015-4

Comment: @JeremyFrench - This is very interesting:  

'The new teaser's voiceover (from 'Jedi')... is delivered by Luke Skywalker himself, though he admits that he kept messing up during one crucial part of it. 

Speaking with AP, Hamill noted that in re-recording the voiceover, he kept saying, "My father had it."... the new piece of dialogue referring to him in present tense suggests he's still alive in some fashion.'

http://blogs.indiewire.com/theplaylist/mark-hamill-suggests-key-star-wars-character-returns-in-the-force-awakens-20150420

Comment: @Pureferret - Doesn't a question about an upcoming movie inherently involve speculative answers based on rapidly changing information?  In this case, waiting for conclusive evidence means waiting so long that the question becomes irrelevant.  By putting this on hold, you are effectively denying any opportunity to get the answer in a timely manner.

Comment: @JeremyFrench - evidence posted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there was an **indication** that someone (possibly Hayden Christiansen himself based on the images) was **considered** for being cast in the early versions of the script.

This comes to us courtesy of [MakingStarWars.net](http://makingstarwars.net/2015/12/the-force-ghost-of-anakin-skywalker-was-proposed-to-be-in-the-force-awakens/), which has uncovered the images of the concept of this in "*Art Of Star Wars: The Force Awakens*" books:

[image]

[image]

Obviously, now that the film is released, we know that they nixed the concept, at least for Episode VII

Answer (score 5):

As someone who has been actively seeking spoilers for the new trilogy, I can say with confidence that - so far - **there has been ZERO evidence indicating that Anakin Skywalker will appear**.

There has been some speculation that Darth Vader will appear in flashback or vision/dream form, but it will likely just be some stuntman in the suit. The voiceover line we hear in the teaser could be pulled from Episode VI, but is more likely just being recited exactly. I say this because, originally, there were longer pauses between the lines "I have it" and "my... sister... has it." Plus, of course, this has the added "You have it." tacked onto the end. It is presumably

> Luke speaking to his adult son/daughter in the movie, who (by all indications) will not know of their origin or Force ability until they find him.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree that the line is being recited; the voice sounds closer to Mark Hamill of 2015 than of 1983

Comment: I threw that last sentence into a spoiler tag just in case. I actively seek spoilers, but I realize others may not.

Comment: @JasonBaker - It is a combination of the recording from Return of the Jedi and a new overdub recorded by Mark Hamill a week before the new teaser leaked.  He says he kept messing up by saying "...my father HAD it.." instead of "...my father HAS it...", so they had to do several takes before he got it right.

http://blogs.indiewire.com/theplaylist/mark-hamill-suggests-key-star-wars-character-returns-in-the-force-awakens-20150420

Comment: I read something last night where someone said Anakin will appear as a Force ghost. I don't believe it, though.

Comment: Interestingly there are rumours he will be in ep VII

Comment: @WadCheber Yup, and here is the Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Drup6kwOAoI&feature=youtu.be&t=1m21s

Answer (score 2):

At present, there is no indication. The most complete cast list (so far) seems to be the one posted by [MakingStarWars.net on April 13th](http://makingstarwars.net/2015/04/star-wars-the-force-awakens-complete-character-list/). Bear in mind that this *is* a fansite, and the source of this information is unclear, so take it with a grain of salt.

I'm not going to reproduce the full list here, because it's quite long, but neither "Anakin Skywalker" nor "Darth Vader" appear on it anywhere. However, the page notes that some of the names are likely codenames rather than actual character names, so it's not impossible that some version of Anakin will feature in the movie.

However, now that the movie has been released, we can confirm that neither Anakin nor Darth Vader make any real appearance (a single shot of Vader's burnt skull notwithstanding).